# How to Create a button in every Cell of a particular column in GRID - EXT JS

Tags: javascript, extjs

Below is my code to create an download link in a everycell of a particular column. This is working fine too.. But in the below code that i used it allows only Icon for the download link. Can anyone please help me how to create a button instead of icon for every cells of the column.

```
this.columns = [ {
            text : 'documentName',
            dataIndex : 'documentName',
            flex : 1.5,
            sortable : true
        }, {
            text : 'documentDescription',
            dataIndex : 'documentDescription',
            flex : 2.5,
            sortable : true
        },
    { text : 'downloadLink',,
            xtype:'actioncolumn',
            flex : 0.5,         
            items: [{
                icon: 'staticfiles/download.png',  // Use a URL in the icon config
                iconCls:'downloadHelpDocIcon',
                tooltip: 'Download',            
                handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                    var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                    //alert("Edit " + rec.get('downloadLink'));

                }
            }]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a button to the items array:

```
text: 'column2',
dataIndex: 'column2',
items: [{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'click',
    ...
}]
```

Comment: Yeah... I did try this.. this shows a button just below the column heading and all the cells values for that column shows the actual content instead of button.

Comment: This is resolved.. below is the code that i have used.                                             {
   xtype:'componentcolumn',
   text: 'Download Link',
            flex : 0.5,
   sortable : false,
   dataIndex : 'downloadLink',   
            
   renderer : function(value, meta, record) {
    
    return {     
     xtype:'button',
     text:'Download',
     listeners : {
      click : function(field, e) {
       alert('clicked');
      }
     }
    };
    
   }
  
            
   
  }

Comment: I'm sorry I completely misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted a button in the header. Which version are you on? You might want to take a look at this:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Widget

Comment: I fear that the xtype componentcolumn no longer exists